# How to make in-line equations the same size as their display counterparts?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, tex-core

For example, if I have something like

```
blah blah blah blah $\frac{1}{1+2x-x^2} + 6$ blah blah blah
```

The equation will look compressed compared to

```
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{1+2x-x^2} + 6 \end{equation}
```

I want my equation to not be compressed like the second code but be in line with the text like the first code. How do I do this?

Comment: Two suggestions: (a) load the `amsmath` package and change `\frac` to `\dfrac`; (b) insert `\displaystyle` after the first `$` symbol.

Comment: Add `\everymath{\displaystyle}` to the preamble.